# How do I have Unique Name for each File?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am interested to know how do I have a unique identityfor each file which is being uploaded on a server asynchronously. I like( www.trello.com ) way of sending request to server, Let say If I uploaded a file on a card with a name "01.gif", It will be sent to the server. And each time when GET request is madethat file come up with it's unique identity like this "527022b97b67b12c12001373".

Can someone have an idea what they have implemented or what should I suppose to do to obtain a unique identifier for each file?

Thanks

Comment: what does this have to do with jQuery or AJAX?

Comment: you could also store the files in the database, then when requested by unique id, output them to the client with the original filename.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the backend technology that you are using, it's difficult to give binding advice, however, in the case of asp.net, you simply assign a new [guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) to the file when the stream is received and then save this guid into your database so that you can readily identify the user that uploaded it etc, as well as any other context based data that you may have included in the post.

The generated guid would have a similar stucture to what you describe, i.e. `0B8A0E7D-C66B-4AAB-A90C-FA7625F51576`.

As mentioned in the comments above, this is not related to ajax or javascript in any way and is related purely to the backend processing.

Comment: Yes, I am using ASP.NET for backend technology. And I will gonna try this out soon.

Answer (score 1):

For your unique site usage, UUID may not be required. If you use PHP for file uploading, you can use filenames like this to save in your disk without collision risk:

```
<?php
//
// get a string like: 4b3403665fea6.gif:
//
$filename = uniqid() . ".gif";
//...
?>
```

Ref.: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uniqid.php